# Vue Nuxt Auth enable auth middleware per route using Class Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-class-components

How can I enable auth middleware per route using Class Components?

What is the equivalent for this:

```
<script>
  export default {
    middleware: 'auth'
  }
</script>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<script>
  import { Vue, Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

  @Component
  export default class Profile extends Vue {
    middleware = 'auth'
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add it as a param in the `Component` decorator.

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component({
  middleware: ['auth']
})
export default class Profile extends Vue {
  name = 'some data'
}
</script>
```

What you did initially will only create a data property. To add component specific option aside from Vue options like `data` `computed` `methods` and `hooks` you have to pass it as a param in the `@Component` decorator

Read more about it [here](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#other-options)